# Clang encoding warning

Tags: xcode, encoding, clang, llvm, osx-mavericks

The latest Xcode has hijacked /usr/bin/gcc and made it mean:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
```

Now every source file of my favorite project, which compiled cleanly with *real* gcc last week, throws a warning:

```
warning: illegal character encoding in string literal [-Winvalid-source-encoding]
```

The source files are encoded in ISO 8859-9. (The execution charset is the same btw.) How can I tell Apple's faux gcc that? In spite of its name, it evidently doesn't understand gcc's -finput-charset flag:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-finput-charset=ISO8859-9' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

Grateful for all hints.

Comment: Or should I be looking for a target architecture option?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! The "Xcode command line tools" provide a real gcc. I ran

```
 xcode-select --install
```

to install them, and I'm back in business.